# How find this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}$

Tags: summation

Find the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sum_{k=2^{n - 1}}^{2^{n}\ -\ 1}\dfrac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}$$

My try:
note
$$\dfrac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}=\dfrac{2}{(2k)(2k+1)(2k+2)}=\left(\dfrac{1}{(2k)(2k+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\right)$$
Then I can't

Comment: It almost looks like the inner term is $2(2k-1)!\over (2k+2)!$...

Answer (score 4):

Throughout, let $H_k\equiv \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j}$ and let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

First, note
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}
&=& \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2^j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}.
\end{eqnarray}

Mathematica says
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=2^j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)} = -\frac{1}{2}\psi(2^j) + \psi(2^j+\frac{1}{2}) - \frac{1}{2} \psi(2^j+1)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). To compute this without as much help from softare, use the original poster's expression for the summand and the fact that
$$
\psi(z+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{n(n+z)}
$$
for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ as long as $z\ne -1,-2,-3,\ldots$.

Using explicit formulas (see Wikipedia) for $\psi(m)$ and $\psi(m+\frac{1}{2})$ where $m$ is an integer, 
\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{1}{2}\psi(2^j) + \psi(2^j+\frac{1}{2}) - \frac{1}{2} \psi(2^j+1) &=&
-\frac{1}{2}H_{2^j-1} - \frac{1}{2} H_{2^j} - 2 \log 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{2^j} \frac{2}{2k-1} \\
&=& -\frac{1}{2}H_{2^j-1} - \frac{1}{2} H_{2^j} - 2 \log 2 + 2(H_{2^{j+1}} - \frac{1}{2} H_{2^j}) \\
&=& -\frac{1}{2}H_{2^j-1} - \frac{3}{2} H_{2^j} - 2 \log 2 + 2 H_{2^{j+1}} \\
&=& -\frac{1}{2}(H_{2^j} -\frac{1}{2^j})  - \frac{3}{2} H_{2^j} - 2 \log 2 + 2 H_{2^{j+1}} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2^{j+1}} - 2 \log 2 + 2 (H_{2^{j+1}} - H_{2^j}).
\end{eqnarray}
Observe
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=0}^m \frac{1}{2^{j+1}} - 2 \log 2 + 2 (H_{2^{j+1}} - H_{2^j})
&=& 1 - 2^{-(m+1)} + 2\left(H_{2^{m+1}}- \log 2^{m+1}\right) - 2H_1.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2^j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)} &=& \lim_{m\to\infty} 1 - 2^{-(m+1)} + 2\left(H_{2^{m+1}}- \log 2^{m+1}\right) - 2H_1 \\
&=& 2\gamma - 1.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a (possibly useless) comment (or commentary? I don't speak English). We have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}\sum_{\substack{n\geq1\\2^{n-1}\leq k<2^n}}n\,;$$

but given $k\geq1$, then  $2^{n-1}\leq k<2^n$ iff $n=\Bigl\lfloor1+\dfrac{\log k}{\log2}\Bigr\rfloor$, so the inner sum is actually equal to this value of $n$, and so the required sum is equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}\cdot\biggl\lfloor1+\dfrac{\log k}{\log2}\biggr\rfloor\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure about the outer $n$? If not, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?f=Sum.sumfunction%5Cu005f1/%28k%282k%2b1%29%282k%2b2%29%29&f=Sum.sumvariable%5Cu005fk&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit_2%5E%28n-1%29&f=Sum.sumupperlimit_2%5En-1&a=*C.summation-_*Calculator.dflt-&_=1383544598832&f3=k&f2=1/%28k%282k%2b1%29%282k%2b2%29%29&f5=2%5En-1&i=summation&f4=2%5E%28n-1%29&fp=1&incTime=true) gives a sum that telescopes nicely
$$\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{k (2 k+1) (2 k+2)}=-2^{-n-1}-\psi^{(0)}(2^{n-1})+\psi^{(0)}(2^n)-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+2^n\right) +\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+2^{n-1}\right)$$

**Update**:
It is not hard to prove user64494's result manually
$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(2k+1)(2k+2)}=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2\left(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)-\left( \frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+2}\right)=$$
$$2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1k-\frac{1}{k+1}=$$
Since $\ln{2}=1-\frac12+\frac13-\cdots$, we have
$$1-\ln{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1}$$
And the second sum is a nicely telescopic one that equals $1$. Therefore
$$S_2=2(1-\ln{2})-\frac12=\frac32-2\ln{2}$$

But this is unfortunately not what you have asked for yet. The real sum you are asking for doesn´t get a closed form from either WolframAlpha or Maple, so I don´t think there is an easy way to get it, at least for me.